# $f(x/a)$ converges to $f(x)$ in $L^1$ as $a\rightarrow 1$ for $f\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem:** For $a > 0$, let $(S_a f)(x) = f(x/a)$ for Lebesgue measurable functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},m)$, $S_a f\rightarrow f$ in $L_1$ as $a\rightarrow 1$.

Can anyone check if my proof below is correct or not? Or is there a simple way? I think the difficulty here is that $f$ is not continuous, so we don't have $S_a f\rightarrow f$ pointwise, thus nullifying any DCT related results.

**My proof:** We are going to follow the routine of: characteristic functions to simple functions to $L^1$ functions.

We first need to show the linearlity of $S_a$. Indeed, $S_a(\alpha f + \beta g) = (\alpha f+\beta g)(x/a) = \alpha f(x/a) + \beta g(x/a) = \alpha S_a(f) + \beta S_a(g)$.

- For $\chi_{I}$ where $I = (b, c)$ is an open interval. It is trivial that $\int |S_a \chi_I - \chi_I| dm \rightarrow 0$.
- Characteristic functions. Let $E$ be a measurable set. Note that in this case we may assume $m(E) <\infty $. We are to prove the argument for $\chi_{E}$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$, by regularity of lebesgue measure, there exists a finite union of disjoint open intervals $A =\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}I_i $ such that $m(A  \triangle E ) < \epsilon / 2$ (Folland, 1.20). We then have
  $$
              \int |S_a\chi_{E} - \chi_{E}| dm \leq \int |S_a\chi_{E} - S_{a}\chi_{A}|dm +\int | S_{a}\chi_{A} - \chi_{A}|dm + \int  |\chi_A - \chi_{E}| dm =\frac{1}{|a|}\epsilon /2 + \epsilon/2 + \int | S_{a}\chi_{A} - \chi_{A}|dm
    $$
  Since $\chi_{A} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \chi_{I_i}$,  $ \int | S_{a}\chi_{A} - \chi_{A}|dm \rightarrow 0$ as $a \rightarrow 1$. Therefore, $\lim_{a\rightarrow 1} \int |S_a\chi_{E} - \chi_{E}| dm \leq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $\int | S_{a}\chi_{E} - \chi_{E}|dm \rightarrow 0$.
- The statement is true for simple functions by linearity.
- Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Given density of simple functions in $L^1$, let $\phi$ be a simple functions such that $ \int|f - \phi| < \epsilon /2$.
  we have $
          \int |S_a f - f| 
          \leq \int |S_a f - S_a \phi |  +  \int |S_{a}\phi - \phi| + \int | \phi - f|
          =\frac{1}{|a|} \epsilon /2 + \epsilon/2 + \int |S_{a}\phi - \phi| 
   $

  Note that $\int |S_{a}\phi - \phi| \rightarrow 0$ as $a\rightarrow 1$. Therefore, $\lim_{a\rightarrow 1 } \int |S_a f - f|  \leq \epsilon $.

  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $S_a{f}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you did, however, I would go directly to a sequence of continuous functions approximating $f$, slightly reducing the effort. In general, if you have an integral statement that you know how to prove immediately for a nice class of functions that are dense, prove it for that class and approximate. Let $\epsilon>0$ and take $f_\epsilon$ continuous with $\|f-f_\epsilon\|_1<\epsilon$.

Then,
$$
\|f(x)-f(x/a)\|_1\leq \|f(x)-f_\epsilon(x)\|_1+\|f_\epsilon(x)-f_\epsilon(x/a)\|_1+\|f_\epsilon(x/a)-f(x/a)\|_1\\
\leq (1+a)\epsilon+\|f_\epsilon(x)-f_\epsilon(x/a)\|_1
$$
by a change of variables. Now you can finish with DCT as you noted.